# R Shiny - Two navbarPage with custom and standard colors each one

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am triyng to have two or even more "navbarPage" on my Shiny App. The first one needs to be colored and the second one needs to have its default style. I tried to pass a class condition in navbarPage, however it doesn't accept it. If I add a .css to it, all navbarPage get that style. Here I have a minimum reproducible example

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(class = "navbar1",
      navbarPage(title="Navbar One",theme="custom-navbar.css",
                                    navbarMenu("Nav 1.1",
                                               tabPanel("Item 1"),
                                               tabPanel("Item 2")),
                                    navbarMenu("Nav 1.2")
                                    )#close nav1
      ), #close div

  navbarPage(title="Navbar Two",
             navbarMenu("Nav 2.1",
                        tabPanel("Item 3"),
                        tabPanel("Item 4")),
             navbarMenu("Nav 2.2",
                        tabPanel("Item 5"),
                        tabPanel("Item 6")),
             navbarMenu("Nav 2.3")
             ), #close nav2

  titlePanel("It is a title panel"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "sidebar panel",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      p("it is a mainpanel")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

.css file

```
.navbar{ background-color: #00b8bd;}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand{color: white;}

.tab-panel{ background-color: #00b8bd; color: #00b8bd}

.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav > .active > a {
color: #fff !important;
background-color:#00b8bd !important;
background-image: #fff !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have put the class navbar1 around your first navbar and updated the .css file to look to this and this is all working.

R

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(class = "navbar1", navbarPage(title="Navbar One",theme="custom-navbar.css")), #custom colors
  navbarPage(title="Navbar Two"), #default colors
  titlePanel("It is a title panel"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "sidebar panel",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      p("it is a mainpanel")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

.css

```
.navbar1 .navbar{ background-color: #00b8bd;}

.navbar1 .navbar-default .navbar-brand{color: white;}

.navbar1 .tab-panel{ background-color: #00b8bd; color: #00b8bd}

.navbar1 .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar1 .navbar-nav > .active > a {
color: #fff !important;
background-color:#00b8bd !important;
background-image: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Knowledge is everything! Just one more thing, I just noticed that this .css leaves selected tab in "navbar 2" colored. How can I fix that?

Comment: Hi, Could you provide the R code which includes the tabs which are doing this.

Comment: Thanks, apologies, I made a small mistake in my intial css. I have updated this now on the above.

Comment: Thank you again! Just a small detail made all the difference! Thank you! I still have a lot to learn about .css! Have a good one!

Comment: Glad to help! Basically, if you put a div and name the class around any part of your shiny code you can then put .whateveryounamedyourclass followed by a space before any css element you wish to edit and this will only change this . The .whateveryounamedyourclass followed by a space means everything under that, without the space it wouldn't work unless the element was directly below it.

Comment: Niceee! Thanks!